# Toast from (@remobile/react-native-toast) doesn't display

Tags: react-native, async-await, toast, catch-block

First, the problem occurs under ios simulator (all virtual devices).

**Dependencies**:
@remobile/react-native-toast": "^1.0.7"
"react-native": "0.56.0"...

**Description of the problem**:
I simulate an api error in an async method like that :

```
async getData() {
 await MyApi.myMethod(...).catch(() => {
   Toast.showLongTop(myToastMessage);
 });
 // Here a toast would be displayed correctly
 }
```

and the toast notification doesn't show itself, even if it does go through the `.catch()`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you made him wrong, try to make your toast like this

ToastAndroid.show('HI world', ToastAndroid.SHORT);